# React onDrag not working but onDragStart works

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a simple component with a draggable icon next to it (going to implement my own Resize).

The code is as follows:

```
type ICanvas = {
    currPageId:string
}
const Canvas:FC<ICanvas> = ({currPageId}) => {
    const story = useStoryStore(state=>state.story);
    const handleDragStart = (e:any) => {
        console.log("start")
    };

    const handleOnDrag = (e:any) => {
        console.log("on drag");
    };
    return (
    <Box {...Styles.CanvasContainer} pos='relative'>
        <div 
            className="resize-button" 
            draggable
            onDrag={handleOnDrag}
            onDragStart={handleDragStart}
            onDragEnd={handleOnDrag}
            >
            <HorizonIcon type='arrow_chevron_down'/>
        </div> 
    </Box>
    )
}

export default Canvas;
```

The onDragStart event fires as it should, but onDrag doesn't work. I tried adding e.stopPropagation/preventDefault everywhere in all possible permutation but nothing.
I even tried using the Chrome inspect event breakpoints and nothing.

I am using latest react version with Chakra UI provider.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So after some digging and a little bit of luck I found out that I had in my system a dependancy of React-dnd-HTML5backend.
With a little google research I found out that this library causes problem with native dragging events within every application it is installed in.

So the solution would be using react-dnd that I already have installed in my project.

Comment: Hi @arthur I know it's been a while since you posted this but I'm stuck in a similar situation. Did you manage to resolve this? If yes could you point me to any resources for implementing this or something similar with react-dnd? Thanks!

Comment: @Shahzaib Hi you are replying to my answer to the issue. I had a dependency that caused problems. The solution was to use react-dnd

Comment: thanks, I had the same issue. I was using react dnd for another purpose which is causing the same problems. I was looking for any resource to help me implement this react dnd